# QuickBooks PHP : Add a javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, quickbooks

I am a beginner in Quick books (https://developer.intuit.com).

I have got VOLT user's and when they enter their ledger account details, i want to show them a confirmation pop up against each fields.

Confirmation pop up is like : a context guidelines/checklist(popup) as and when a user is entering the details in a ledger transaction for a trust account in QB online. The checklist will be a series of Yes/No questions.

In another simple way i want to show a pop in QB online form and i want to save in database.

I found https://www.pipethru.com/enterprise/Webhooks/QuickbooksOnline.

But in this i am not able get how to validate a form data.

Please advice...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function delete_produkt(aa,bb,cc){
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:200,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Artikel löschen": function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/aaaa.php",
            data: {aa: aa,bb: bb,cc: cc},
            beforeSend: function() {
            $('#prikaz_info').html('');},
            success: function() {
            $('#prikaz_info').load("ajax/loaddata.php");
            },
            error: function() {
            alert("Keine Verbindung !");
            }
            }); 
            $('#redak'+br+'').remove(); 
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Abbrechen: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }}});}
</script>
```